# How to chain tasks in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am working on android app registration in which I need to perform several tasks one by one let  say

task1
task2
task3

I want to chain these tasks one after another and if a task is failed whole process should be failed..

I want to solve this problem by Rxjava can anyone tell me how to achieve this with rxJava.

(I have wasted 5 hours but did not find solution also newbie in RxJava)

**What I have tried**

```
Observable.merge(task1,task2,task3).subscribe(new Observer<DataError>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(DataError dataError) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
             //this method is not called by rxJava
            }
        });
```

with this method all things are working fine but `onComplete()` method is not called by rxJava .

Please help~

**Edit-**

Each task is dependent on previous task result.and there should be one task at one time.

Comment: First, `merge()` does not do tasks one by one, it will subscribe to the sources at the same time, meaning all your tasks will run in parallel, so `merge()` is not the right operator here.

Comment: Also, the question is missing few details. First make sure all of your tasks complete. Many `Observable` don't complete; many of them run indefinitely as long as there is any subscriber attached to them. If your tasks are designed to run only one time, use `Single`, `Completable`, or `Maybe`, instead of `Observable`. Also, you need to clarify the dependencies among the tasks. For example, to run task2 you might need the result of task1, etc.

Comment: thank you for replying sir,
yes there is  dependencies of each task from previous task like 
tast1 is dependent on task2,task3 on task4

Comment: how to do it with Single?

Comment: `Single` also has `flatMap()`, so you can replace `Observable` in @arungiri_10 answer with `Single` then it will work. Note that `Single` emits only one time like its name suggests so `just()` method will take only one value.

Comment: That reminds me there could be different types of dependencies. For example, if task3 depends on task2 and task2 depends on task1 then you can say task3 is sort of indirectly depends on task1, compared to the scenarios where task3 is directly depends on the output of task1. You will need a different structure in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say we have 3 tasks. From given array of Integers, Find even numbers, Multiply each even numbers with 10, Divide each number by 2

```
//A stream of observable to find even numbers
private Observable<Integer> findEven(Integer number) {
    return Observable
        .just(number)
        .filter(data -> data % 2 == 0);
}

//A stream of observable to multiply each number with 10
private Observable<Integer> multiplyBy10(Integer evenNumber) {
    return Observable.just(evenNumber).map(data -> data * 10);
}

//A stream of observable to divide each number with 2
private Observable<Integer> divideBy2(Integer evenNumber) {
    return Observable.just(evenNumber).map(data -> data / 2);
}
```

So, how do we chain this task?

```
Observable
    .just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    //find even numbers
    .flatMap(num -> findEven(num))
    //Now multiply each even number by 10
    .flatMap(num -> multiplyBy10(num))
    //Now to each number divide 2 
    .flatMap(num -> divideBy2(num))
    .subscribe(
        // result: 10, 20, 30, 40
        result -> Log.v("", "result: " + result),
        error -> Log.e("", error.getMessage())
    );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: comprehensive answer. Nothing to add even)

Comment: let me please try it